# Seaching widgets in zk

Tags: widget, zk

Is it possible to find all widgets that have id begining from string in zk ?
jquery example:

```
 $( "input[id^='news']" ).val( "news here!" );
```

In zk maybe something like this:

```
 zk.Widget.$([id^='news']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to find widget id (Widget and not Component) you can use :

```
zk.Widget.$(jq("input[id^='news']"));
```

In fact "jq" is equivalent of "$" in ZK.

> ZK Client Engine is based on jQuery. It inherits all functionality
>   provided by jQuery

[http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/jsdoc/*global*/jq.html](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/jsdoc/_global_/jq.html)

Warning :

ZK use 2 terms for widget/component :

- Component for Server Side (java and zul)
- Widget for Client Side (DOM and js)

ZK generate unique id for widgets, that's why you could not find component ID (zul or java id), with standard jquery selector (with $ or jq).

If you need to find a widget with it's component id use :

```
jq("$componentid");
```

I am pretty sure, it's impossible to write a selector for matching the begining of components id.

Change your code (if possible) to use Component SCLASS attribute (class attribute for DOM element) it should be way more simple !

Her an example for selection of all "Button" component with sclass "findme" :

```
zk.Widget.$(jq("@button.findme"));
```